# Changing row color on row expansion

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9

I am working on an angular app. I am using primeng row expansion table feature in it.

Code with example is as follows:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v12/#/table/rowexpansion

Stackblitz :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablerowexpansion-demo

I want to change color of the row when it is expanded. suppose table inside expansion is yellow color, when user clicks expansion icon, the row which is expanded should become yellow color. how to  do it?

Comment: Hi, Please check my answer and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best Wishes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have solution for you. You can use `[ngStyle]` and `background-color` in the `<tr>` tag.
**Here is your HTML**

```
<tr [ngStyle]="{'background-color':expanded ? 'green' : 'white' }">
            <td>
                <button type="button" pButton pRipple [pRowToggler]="product" class="p-button-text p-button-rounded p-button-plain" [icon]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'"></button>
            </td>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>           
            <td><p-rating [ngModel]="product.rating" [readonly]="true" [cancel]="false"></p-rating></td>
            <td><span [class]="'product-badge status-' + product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()">{{product.inventoryStatus}}</span></td>
        </tr>
```

You can also bind a function with `[ngStyle]=getStyles(product,expanded)` to add more conditions.

```
getStyles(product:any,expanded:any)
{
  //USE your Logic
  let myStyles = {
  'background-color': 'green'
  }
  return myStyles;
}
```

**Note:** I have updated your code in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablerowexpansion-demo-emcmj4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Please check the code.